# Hibernate: какие поля в таблице для ArrayList,int[][]?

Tags: hibernate, java

Использую в проекте Hibernate. Почитал как работать с коллекциями, но кое что не ясно:
Есть информация, как работать и что писать для коллекции в xml-файле, который описывает класс. А вот какая таблица должна соответствовать этому классу?

1. К примеру клас с тремя полями `int id; int[][] и ArrayList<Person> persons;` Как должна выглядеть таблица для такого класса(не важно какая БД)? И если можно xml-файл? О Геттерах, Сеттерах и станд конструкторе знаю.
2. И на счет своих простых классов я правильно понимаю – достаточно создать табличку с такими же полями как у нашего класса переменные которые хотим сохранять, описать ее и дальше писать функции для того, чтобы тащить из БД и писать?
3. И еще вопрос, к примеру, я сохраняю в одном классе такой `ArrayList<Person> persons;` - это значит, что в классе Person на все переменные тоже должны быть Геттеры, сеттеры и так далее?

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я понимаю, коллекции удобны, для осуществления связи между отельными классами (сущностями в базе), т.е. когда над полями пишут аннотации @OneToMany и @ManyToMany.

Например, есть таблица машин и человеков. Каждый человек может быть владельцем одной машины, а любая машина принадлежит единственному человеку. Тогда целесообразно указать в классе человека поле-коллекцию типизированную машиной, написав над ним аннотацию @OneToMany.

Поэтому, если вы хотите хранить коллекцию (массив например) в одном поле таблицы, то наверняка нужно написать отдельный класс X, который будет сериализуемым и добавить поле X в класс, представляющий сущность записи БД. А Hibernate Entity Manager сделает за Вас всё остальное.

Comment: Спасибо, как бы все понятно, но кусочек кода был бы наглядней...
А как быть с такими объектами как Color например? Если есть кусочек кода поделитесь...

Comment: http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/one-to-many-jpa-template-config-jpa-entity-config.html